# A escrita dessa função esta correta?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Fiz essa função para que ela pegasse uma requisição do js e na hora de inserir o nome de uma categoria, dar um select no banco, verificar se já existe o nome e caso retornar 0 no count, ele gravar.

EStá gravando, mas quando insiro um mesmo nome, ele ainda não respeita a condição. Alguém sabe me dizer porque?

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

    try{

            $compara = DB::select("SELECT nome FROM categorias WHERE nome = '.$request->nome.'");


            if(count($compara) == 0)
            {
               $categoria = new Categoria();

               $categoria->fill($request->json()->all());
               $categoria->save();

               return response()->json($categoria, 201); //201 - created 
            }

        }

    catch(\Exception $ex){
        return response()->json(["error"=>$ex->getMessage() . ' on line: ' . $ex->getLine()], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo Carlos ? a minha resposta?

Answer (score 0):

O [DB::select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries) é mais utilizado para retornar `array` de valores como precisa verificar se já cadastrou algum item pelo nome utilize [DB::table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results) com `where` e por fim o método chame o método `count()` da seguinte forma:

```
$count = DB::table('categorias')->where('nome',100)->count();
```

Exemplo no código:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $count = DB::table('categorias')
                ->where('nome',$request->nome)
                ->count();  
        if($count == 0)
        {
           $categoria = new Categoria();
           $categoria->fill($request->json()->all());
           $categoria->save();
           return response()->json($categoria, 201); //201 - created 
        }

    }
    catch(\Exception $ex){
        return response()->json(
            ["error"=>$ex->getMessage().' on line: '.$ex->getLine()], 
                500
        );
    }
}
```

<sub>Referencias:</sub>

- [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)